# Scala case class Option value chaining

Tags: scala, scala-collections

```
case class Person(@BsonProperty("first_name") firstName:Option[String],@BsonProperty("second_name")  secondName:Option[String],@BsonProperty("person_age") var  age:Int)


val me = Some(Person(Some(Ambareesh),Some(B),23))

      Or

val me = None

      Or

val me = Some(Person(Some(Ambareesh),None,23))

     Or

val me = Some(Person(None,None,23))


someOperation(me.secondName / None) //How can I implement this behavior in single line.
someOperation(me.firstName / None)


def someOperation(name:Option[String]){
   //Do ...
 }
```

My doubt regarding the argument (instance of Person) to method `someOperation`. The argument itself is an Option value and fields are also Options. If either of this is `None`(argument or argument.fieldName) I want `None` as return else the field value as Some(fieldValue). Is it possible?

Comment: I am sorry. I couldnt understand the question

Comment: `val me = Some(Person(Some(Ambareesh),Some(B),23))`.

`me.get.firstName.get` should return `None / firstName` i.e Option[String]
similarly `me.get.secondName.get`.

I have more parameters like firstName and secondName so I should able to refer it in the function call itself.

Comment: Isn't `me.firstName` already an `Option`?

Comment: @Jatin No, `me.firstName` doesn't compile.

Comment: yes `me.get.firstName` will work if me is not `None`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
someOperation(me.flatMap(_.secondName))
```

See [ScalaDoc](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.6/scala/Option.html#flatMap[B](f:A=%3EOption[B]):Option[B]).

You can use `map` for non-`Option` properties: `me.map(_.age)` is `Option[Int]`.

Answer (score 2):

If your `someOperation` returns an Option that you could also use a `for` comprehension.

```
val result: Option[String] = for {
   person <- me
   firstName <- someOperation(person.firstName)
   secondName<- someOperation(person.secondName)
} yield <use firstName, secondName here>
```

This will give you whatever result you want to calculate or `None`.

Comment: but `me` can be `None`. I have edited the question clarify this.

Comment: Yes and that makes no difference to the for comprehension and you'll just get None in the end. Using either this or any of the other answers is just a matter of style as there are many ways to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

As I understood, you need to extract person fields and pass it into the method someOperation. Right?

If so, you can use pattern matching for this:

```
someOperation(
  me match {
    case Some(person) => person.firstName
    case None => None
  } 
)
```